# При работе с функцией Postgres где нужно делать транзакцию и как правильно?

Tags: php, postgresql, хранимые-процедуры

Есть какая-то функция в *Postges*, которая из разных таблиц должна удалить данные. Естественно в результате работы может что-то пойти не так.

- Правильно ли я понимаю, что в  *Postges* внутри функции нельзя открывать транзакции и коммитить/откатывать?
- Правильно ли я понимаю, что в транзакцию надо помещать вызов этой самой функции из кода *PHP*?
- Когда в *PHP* открываю и закрываю транзакцию, то по сути драйвер БД "говорит" самой БД эту команду (BEGIN) исполнить, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в Postges внутри функции нельзя открывать транзакции и коммитить/откатывать?

Да, *функция* выполняется строго в транзакции и не может управлять внешней транзакцией.

*Процедура* управлять транзакцией может. Поддержка процедур ([`create procedure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html) и вызов через `call`, соответственно) была добавлена в postgresql 11.

> в транзакцию надо помещать вызов этой самой функции из кода PHP?

На усмотрение автора кода.

Вызов хранимой функции в любом случае будет внутри транзакции, явно выполненной приложением либо неявно открытой только на этот sql запрос с вызовом функции. PostgreSQL строго транзакционная база, у вас нет опции "запустить запрос вне транзакции", запрос будет в транзакции всегда, даже если вы об этом явно не просили.

> Когда в PHP открываю и закрываю транзакцию, то по сути драйвер БД "говорит" самой БД эту команду (BEGIN) исполнить, так?

[Да, верно.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_driver.c#L519)

Comment: "запрос будет в транзакции всегда, даже если вы об этом явно не просили." - т.е. получается что даже в PHP не надо будет открывать транзакцию и если в функции выполняется 10 запросов на удаление из разных таблиц и что-то не так пошло - то ничего ниоткуда не удалится? В PHP надо в try/catch просто обернуть? Или даже оборачивать не надо?

Comment: (если не усложнять происходящее явными и неявными savepoint) да, если функция будет прервана ошибкой - то всё уже выполненные в ней изменения будут отменены.

Comment: А можно последний вопрос? Как в коде PHP понять, что функция исполнилась успешно, а не произошёл сбой и всё откатилось? Ведь функция получается в любом случае выполнится?

Comment: Функция в базе выполнится только если выполнится. Если не выполнится - база отрапортует ошибку. Как это увидеть приложению - уточните для своей библиотеки. Для pdo_pgsql например поведение меняется в зависимости от PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE. Если выставлено в PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION - то будет исключение при ошибке.

Comment: А, понял, то есть всё же try/catch можно писать. Спасибо